# ElementUI doing validation with Sub Component

Tags: vue.js, validation, element-ui

How to validate a sub component inside a form?

In the form component I have the sub component:

```html
<template>
  <el-form :model="value">
    <el-form-item 
      prop="name" 
      :rules="{ required: true, message: 'Necessary', trigger: 'blur' }"
    >
      <el-input v-model="value.name">
    </el-form-item>
    <ZipCode v-model="value.zipcode" />
  </el-form>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: { 
      type: Object, 
      default: () => { 
        return { 
          name: null, 
          zipcode: { code: null, local: null }
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And in the ZipCode component:

```html
<template>
  <el-form-item 
    prop="code" 
    :rules="{ required: true, message: 'Necessary', trigger: 'blur' }"
  >
    <el-input v-model="value.code">
  </el-form-item>

  <el-form-item 
    prop="local" 
    :rules="{ required: true, message: 'Necessary', trigger: 'blur' }"
  >
    <el-input v-model="value.local">
  </el-form-item>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: { 
      type: Object, 
      default: () => { return { code: null, local: null } } 
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The validation on the form component is working as expected but not the validation on the sub component. If the field has data, still gives the error that data is required. This false validation is also working from the form component.

So problem might be on the "prop" field. If change the prop to "value.code" or "zipcode.code" it gives the error "Error: please transfer a valid prop path to form item".

What might be the issue? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Try fixing the typos on the `<el-form-item>`, they are ending with `)` instead of `>`.  If that doesn't fix it, you should post the validation code

Comment: @Dan Thank you, that was just a typo. The validation is done automatically by ElementUI following the :rules property.

Comment: The `</el-form>` is also not closed properly.  Most importantly, it would be good to see your `value` object from the parent script

Comment: @Dan Ok, just added.

Comment: Still not enough code. You're using props for the form model and we can't see what the object's full structure is because it's a prop (not to mention it's being mutated, which is a no-no)

Comment: @Dan Thank you for your feedback. After many hours seaching I finaly found a thread from 2016 that pointed to the right direction. All the best.

Comment: It's possible to declare the rules once on the form element, or per item.  The question showed the per item method, but that solution uses the form method.  Maybe the per item method didn't work with your form because you're [mutating props](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow) 

Comment: @Dan Hello. Yes, you're right, the solution is on the form element. But it can also add an el-form-item with the rule before the ZipCode element. Thank you for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule should have the type as an 'object' with a fields property for each sub rule.

```
  <el-form :model="value" :rules="
    {
      name: [
        { required: true, message: 'Please input name', trigger: 'blur' }
      ],
      zipcode: {
        type: 'object',
        required: true,
        fields: {
          code: { type: 'string', required: true, len: 8, message: 'invalid zip' },
          local: { type: 'string', required: true, message: 'required' }
        }
      }
    }
  ">
```